# Automate deleting Rows and replace with lower rows in Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way using excel VBA so that any time that a particular row of an Excel spreadsheet that is in between rows that have some content is emptied in all its cells, that the lower rows are copied upwards. I.e. suppose that row 1-10 have content and I delete the content at row 5, then row 6 becomes row 5, row 7 becomes row 6 etc until row 10 becomes row 9 and the operation is finished. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have do edit and try it for your needs. You should note that the loop from the bottom moves upward and the Excel spreadsheet has five fixed lines at top.

```
Sub Delete_Empty_Lines()
  Dim quotes As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim usedRows As Long
  Dim row As Long

  '// usedRows = Sheets("Sheet-1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  usedRows = Sheets("Sheet-1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  For row = usedRows To 5 Step -1
    If Sheets("Sheet-1").Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
      quotes = MsgBox("Sheet-1 has empty lines - delete this line?", vbYesNo)
      Select Case quotes
        Case vbYes
          Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete
          '// Exit Sub
        Case vbNo
          Exit Sub
      End Select
    End If
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

**Edit:** Code sample to insert a line:

```
Private Sub cmdFillData_Click()
  '//--- clean and fill in some data ----------------------------------
  Sheets("AreaData").Select
  Worksheets("AreaData").Cells.Clear
  Range("A1").Select
  Range("A1:C1") = Array("Germany", "Berlin", "Brandenburg Gate")
  Range("A2:C2") = Array("South Africa", "Cape Town", "Waterfront")
  Range("A3:C3") = Array("France", "Paris", "Eiffel Tower")
  Range("A4:C4") = Array("Spain", "Madrid", "Plaza Mayor")
  Range("A5:C5") = Array("Italy", "Rome", "Palazzo Senatorio")

  '//--- search for value -------------------------------------
  Columns("A:A").Select
  Cells.Find(What:="France", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

  '//--- Insert row above active cell
  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
  ActiveCell.Select

  '//--- Insert row below active cell
  'ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

  '//--- Insert column to the left of the active cell
  'ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert

  '//--- Insert column to the right of the active cell
  'ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert

End Sub
```

Comment: @ help-info.de So basically Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete does the job? what ensures the copying of higher index rows to lower index rows?

Comment: It's old stuff and yes Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete
 does the job. The copying job is the same as done manually.

Comment: Is there a similar function for adding rows in between 2 rows? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. BTW - please use Stack Overflow's [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) e.g. `excel insert line` to avoid duplicate questions.